# How to display firebase data in Angular template

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this data in firebase I want to display in html using Angular 4, when I try adding json to it( {{ order.items | json  }}), it displays the whole result but does not format in a table like structure for ease to read. Can anyone help.

[This the structure of the database, I want to get customer orders which includes items(product, quantity and totalPrice) and in product get the imageUrl,price and title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBdJH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prismjs` to prettyfi the output.

Something like this:

```
<pre [innerHtml]="sortedObject | prettyjson:2" #prettyObjectElement></pre>
```

You can know more [here](https://auralinna.blog/post/2017/code-syntax-highlighting-with-angular-and-prismjs)

Comment: is there another solution I can use, I didn't seem to understand how this works even from the documentation. Thanks